# How to fix subversion password config?

Tags: svn, passwords, svn-checkout

I want that everytime someone wants to checkout the project from SVN he/she will be prompted for credentials. This happens when someone tries to commit something, but not at checkout. Here is the svnserve.conf section :

```
[general]
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
```

I figured that by setting anon-access to none, this will prompt for a username & password, but this doesn't seem to happen. How can I fix this? What do I need to change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set

```
auth-access = rw
```

a checkout doesn't write, it only reads. If you want to have your users enter their credentials on a checkout, you have to make reads also authenticated.

Comment: now I get "svn: No access allowed to this repository". I tried connecting with the user in the passwd file by specifying the username & password as command line arguments. If I try to checkout by using svn checkout svn_url, I get the same "no access allowed..." message. What can I do to fix that?

Comment: after adding auth-access = read and auth-access = write, it worked.

Comment: Do we need to do any thing extra eg to restart the machine etc.. as it didn't work for me...I created repository in the same machine...

Comment: This doesn't take effect if we are using file url . Is there any way to protect the repo while using file url?

Answer (score 3):

```
auth-access = rw
```

did not work for me.
As mentioned in the comment by @Tempus, I had to do this:

```
auth-access = read
auth-access = write
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Also, it's started to work for me when I uncomment  "password-db = passwd".

Comment: You are overwriting auth-access by using it twice, write includes read privileges.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't ensure that *every* access will prompt the user for the password as the clients usually do cache the password. Or do you want to make read accesses password protected regardless of client caching?

Comment: i know caching happens, but the first time, a client still need to enter his password. the caching is done client-side.

Comment: I did say that clients do cache, did I? Unfortunately your question was unclear in that regard -- at least to me.